# Time difference between consecutive records for specific status in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with following structure. I am using SQL Server 2016

| pkey | statusDate | Status | StatusEntryID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-07 11:49:59.430 | Accept | 7 |
| 2 | 2021-10-07 11:51:50.430 | Processed | 7 |
| 3 | 2021-10-07 11:52:52.883 | Dispatched | 7 |
| 4 | 2021-10-07 11:55:37.263 | Delivered | 7 |

Please note: these status entries will be always in chronological order but one can override the normal flow and jump to any status directly. For example, from `Accept` we can even jump to `Delivered` status.

What I am trying to achieve is a result which shows us the time differences between 2 states

For example - expected output is

```
EntryId   Time_Approve    Time_Process    Time_Dispatch Time_Delivered
7         0               15              23             8
```

One thing to note in the sample is regarding Approve Status, which is not available in physical table. if its there only consider them in calculations.

I tried using Lag and Lead functions but couldn't achieve the desired result. Please help

Comment: What if it is delivered before accepted? Why is Time_approve 0? Should it always be zero?

Comment: The status entries will be always in Chronological Orders. It will never alter the sequential status. Hence delivered wont come before accepted. But jumping can happen. In this case After Accept it directly went to Processed skipping the status Approve

Comment: @Surensiveaya, Time difference in terms of what? minutes/hours/etc.,?

Comment: @Arun - in seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you use conditional aggregation to convert the 4 rows into 4 columns, then use `COALESCE` to find the time of previous state (it must be done in reverse order). Finally you use `DATEDIFF`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT StatusEntryID
         , t1 = MIN(CASE WHEN Status = 'Accept'     THEN StatusDate END)
         , t2 = MIN(CASE WHEN Status = 'Processed'  THEN StatusDate END)
         , t3 = MIN(CASE WHEN Status = 'Dispatched' THEN StatusDate END)
         , t4 = MIN(CASE WHEN Status = 'Delivered'  THEN StatusDate END)
    FROM t
    GROUP BY StatusEntryID
)
SELECT StatusEntryID
     , Time_Accept    = 0
     , Time_Process   = DATEDIFF(SECOND, t1, t2)
     , Time_Dispatch  = DATEDIFF(SECOND, COALESCE(t2, t1), t3)
     , Time_Delivered = DATEDIFF(SECOND, COALESCE(t3, t2, t1), t4)
FROM cte
```

All values are in seconds. Converting to hour/minute/seconds is trivial.